# Validator not using specified rules, passes when should fail, using way/database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-validation

I'm using the [way/database](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-Model-Validation) package for validation with Laravel 4.2 and have set up a simple user registration method.

I'm testing this by trying to create a new user with an email address that is already present. The validator returns true, and then goes onto give the error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'test2@test.com' for key 'users_email_unique' (SQL: insert into `users` (`email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (test2@test.com, 123, 2015-01-29 11:50:37, 2015-01-29 11:50:37))
```

So is this something wrong with my model?

The controller:

```
public function store()
{
    $user = User::create(Input::only('email', 'password'));

    if ($user->hasErrors()){
        return Response::json(array(
            'error' => $user->getErrors()
        ));
    }

    Auth::login($user);

    return Response::json(array('success' => 'true'));
}
```

The `User.php` model:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Model implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    protected $fillable = array(
        'email', 'password'
    );

    protected static $rules = [
        'email' => 'required:unique'
    ];

    //Use this for custom messages
    protected static $messages = [
        'email.required' => 'An email address is required'
    ];

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

}
```

Here's the validation model from `way/database`:

```
class Model extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * Error message bag
     * 
     * @var Illuminate\Support\MessageBag
     */
    protected $errors;

    /**
     * Validation rules
     * 
     * @var Array
     */
    protected static $rules = array();

    /**
     * Custom messages
     * 
     * @var Array
     */
    protected static $messages = array();

    /**
     * Validator instance
     * 
     * @var Illuminate\Validation\Validators
     */
    protected $validator;

    public function __construct(array $attributes = array(), Validator $validator = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);

        $this->validator = $validator ?: \App::make('validator');
    }

    /**
     * Listen for save event
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::saving(function($model)
        {
            return $model->validate();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Validates current attributes against rules
     */
    public function validate()
    {
        $v = $this->validator->make($this->attributes, static::$rules, static::$messages);

        if ($v->passes())
        {
            return true;
        }

        $this->setErrors($v->messages());

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Set error message bag
     * 
     * @var Illuminate\Support\MessageBag
     */
    protected function setErrors($errors)
    {
        $this->errors = $errors;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve error message bag
     */
    public function getErrors()
    {
        return $this->errors;
    }

    /**
     * Inverse of wasSaved
     */
    public function hasErrors()
    {
        return ! empty($this->errors);
    }

}
```

Can anyone point me towards what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
protected static $rules = [
    'email' => 'required:unique'
];
```

to

```
protected static $rules = [
    'email' => 'required|unique'
];
```

The Laravel docs will help
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation